# What is this openvt command doing?

Tags: tty, getty, chvt

What is this command really doing (step by step)?

```
openvt -c 40 /bin/agetty tty40 linux
```

I tried this command instead :

```
openvt -c 41 /bin/agetty tty40 linux
```

and agetty was started on tty40 (not tty41). Why is that? It seems the `-c 41` option is not necessary. Removing it yields the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
openvt -c 40 /bin/agetty tty40 linux
```

runs `openvt`, directing it to use VT 40; so it opens that VT, and runs `agetty` on it. But specifying `tty40` as an argument to `agetty` tells the latter to use VT 40 (regardless of where it was started), so it opens VT 40 itself and runs there.

Thus,

```
openvt -c 41 /bin/agetty tty40 linux
```

opens VT 41, but then `agetty` opens VT 40 itself.

You should just use one program to open the VT. You can either run `agetty` directly on whichever VT you want, or tell it to run wherever it’s been started:

```
agetty tty40 linux
openvt -c 40 agetty - linux
```

If you remove the `-c` option, `openvt` will pick the first available VT.

Comment: Thank you! But if I am on tty2 and I use directly `agetty tty40 linux`, after I type my username, agetty is replaced by `login`, which is executed on tty2. Is this expected? How can I use directly agetty in a way that assures that `login` is executed on tty40 as well?

Comment: That’s odd; when I tried it, I got the login on the same VT as `agetty`. This might be a silly question, but are you running `agetty` as root?

Comment: I was not. I tried it as root, but I still get the same behavior. When I type my username and Enter, nothing happens on tty40, but on tty2, I am asked for my username, as if agetty had respawned. I am not sure it is the login program actually... It seems like both tty40 and tty2 stopped and tty2 just happened to respawn automatically as it should.

Comment: Yes, if you’re asked to enter your username again, that’s `agetty`, not `login`. (`agetty` asks for a username, then replaces itself with `login` to process the login, including asking for a password if appropriate.) Does the second variant work? (`openvt -c 40 agetty - linux`)

Comment: Yes, the second variant works. It is weird that the first does not. So, on tty2, `agetty tty40 linux` is waiting until the command exits. On tty40, after entering my username on tty40, agetty stops and should be replaced by `login`, but it is not. On tty2, when agetty exits, it is like I exited the shell as well.

Comment: Bit of a head-scratcher that, I’m afraid I’m out of ideas...